# Jquery trying to get src using html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the src from this jquery html().

So using jquery html() my alert shows this output

what I want is the src. See code below:

```
 var $boxes = $(".slideWrap"),
                var hdnImg = $boxes.first().show();
                var p = hdnImg.html(); //OUTPUTS <img src="../image090.png" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__Graphics1">
                alert(p.attr("src")); // DOES NOT WORK??
```

Why is p.attr("src") does not work? I am trying to get the html and then getting the src from the html.

Any one please help?

Comment: you want `hdnImg.attr("src")`

Comment: Tried that errors "undefined" message appears. Is there a way of getting src from jquery html().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) `.html()` returns a string. Strings don't have an `.attr()` method.

If you want the attribute from the element, the use `.attr()` on the element that has the attribute you want.

---

Here's another part of the problem...

```
var p = hdnImg.html(); //OUTPUTS <img src="../image090.png" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__Graphics1">
```

Because the output shows the HTML of the `<img>`, and the `.html()` method returns the HTML ***content***, then that means the image is nested.

To get the image, you need to traverse down to it. Do this instead...

```
var p = hdnImg.children('img').html();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for

```
hdnImg.children('img').attr('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont want the html, you want the jQuery wrapped DOM element: `hdnImg.attr("src");`

Answer (score 0):

`p` is not a JQuery object.

Try:

```
$(p).attr("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your hdnImg variable is not the actually IMG element, but the parent element (i.e. whatever has `.slideWrap` for a class)

first get the img element like this:

```
var img = hdnImg.find("IMG");
```

then you can get `src` like

```
var src = img.attr("src");
```